# XSLT extension function with libxslt

Tags: c++, libxml2, libxslt

I am trying to create an xslt extension function for libxslt (c++). My extension function takes a string as input, then this string is parsed by xml parser, and the function returns this parsed xml. I return value by this expression:

```
void fnParse(xmlXPathParserContextPtr ctx, int nargs)
{
    ...
    xmlXPathReturnNodeSet(ctx, xmlXPathNodeSetCreate(node));
}
```

But I have found that libxslt does not free node memory after use. It free xmlNodeSet, but not free the node which is stored in this nodeset. Perhaps I missed something important. What is the correct way to return an XML node in the extension function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and register a "result value tree" by calling xsltCreateRVT
and xsltRegisterLocalRVT, then add the nodes you want to return to that tree.
Have a look at functions like exsltStrTokenizeFunction to see how it works:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt/-/blob/master/libexslt/strings.c